# Matzah meal as a binder in veggie burgers

Tags: substitutions, vegetarian

I'm experimenting with veggie burgers, and I keep seeing rolled oats and breadcrumbs in recipes such as [this one](http://www.geniuskitchen.com/recipe/vegan-lentil-burgers-224363#activity-feed). However, I grew up in a Jewish home where the binder in recipes such as this one would be eggs and matzah meal. In what ratio can I replace the rolled oats and breadcrumbs with eggs and matzah meal?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the matzah meal is the equivalent of finer grain breadcrumbs. So what ever ratio you would usually use for breadcrumbs + eggs I'd do the same for matzah meal.